# AWS S3 upload fails with ACL public-true

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this simple script in Ruby to upload a file on S3 I got from AWS documentation:

```
def object_uploaded?(s3_resource, bucket_name, object_key, file_path)
  object = s3_resource.bucket(bucket_name).object(object_key)
  File.open(file_path, 'rb') do |file|
    object.put(body: file, acl: 'public-read')
  end
  return true
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error uploading object: #{e.message}"
  return false
end
```

The script gives me Access Denied when i add **acl: 'public-read'**. Works fine if I remove that.

Only way for this to work is to make my S3 bucket public.
[image]

This is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1610635552932",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1610635551842",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[mybucket]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
                "s3:CreateJob"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[mybucket]",
                "arn:aws:s3:::[mybucket]/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way I can turn on **Block public access** as recommended by AWS and have public accessible files by setting the acl? What is wrong with my policy?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to achieve? Your object is public or it is private. It does not matter if you make it public using ACL or bucket policy - public is public.

Comment: S3 ACLs is a legacy access control mechanism that predates IAM. You don't need to change if you already use it, but I advice you to avoid it when you can on new projects.

Comment: What I’m trying to achieve is to upload a file and make it publicly accessible. I thought I could do it by setting ACL without changing bucket setting. But apparently I can’t even upload a file with ACL public-read if the bucket Block public access is on.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a file with ACL public-read if the bucket's block public access setting is on. Per the documentation: "Amazon S3 block public access prevents the application of any settings that allow public access to data within S3 buckets." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access.html)